# UISplitViewController Rotation Master Master on iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: objective-c, iphone, storyboard, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

So if you create a UISplitViewController with 'MasterView' and 'DetailView' setup like this

[image]

in the 'MasterView' in portrait on the iPhone 6 Plus you push/show 'MasterView2' by pressing the item button and then you rotate the device I would expect to see this - 'MasterView2' | 'DetailView'

[image]

but instead I get 'MasterView' | 'MasterView2'

[image]

How should this be setup so on rotating the iPhone 6 Plus I get the expected 'MasterView2' | 'DetailView'?

Comment: Can you show any of your code? Are you overriding splitViewControllerPreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for anyone interested here is how I solved the problem, using the splitviewcontroller delegate

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController
collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController
ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController{
   return YES;
}

- (UIViewController *)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController
separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController     *)primaryViewController{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    return [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailView"];
}
```