# UISplitViewController with Master view have 2 Table views

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller, iphone-6-plus

I'm programming an app running on iPhone 6 plus use UISplitViewController like this:

[image]

When I tested on iPhone 6 plus in portrait, the DetailView do not display. If I open to Table2View then I change to landscape, the Table1View display on the left and the Table2View display on the right.
I want the Table2View display on the left and the DetailView display on the right. How will I do?

**Solution:** I found solution here: [UISplitViewController Rotation Master Master on iPhone 6 Plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852800/uisplitviewcontroller-rotation-master-master-on-iphone-6-plus). This is my code:

```
- (UIViewController *)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController
separateSecondaryViewControllerFromPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController {
    if ([primaryViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UIViewController *topViewController = [(UINavigationController *)primaryViewController topViewController];
        if ([topViewController isKindOfClass:[Table2ViewController class]]) {
            return [topViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

**But now I get other issue.** With this line of code:

```
return [topViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
```

the app will show like this:

[image]

If now I change the app to portrait, it will crash after run this code (return NO):

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitViewController collapseSecondaryViewController:(UIViewController *)secondaryViewController ontoPrimaryViewController:(UIViewController *)primaryViewController {
    if ([secondaryViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] && [[(UINavigationController *)secondaryViewController topViewController] isKindOfClass:[DetailViewController class]] && ([(DetailViewController *)[(UINavigationController *)secondaryViewController topViewController] item] == nil)) {
        // Return YES to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is that DetailViewController is added is not valid. How can I fix it?

**Solution:** I solved this issue too. This is a perfect sample: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/AdaptivePhotos/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014636

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I found solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852800/uisplitviewcontroller-rotation-master-master-on-iphone-6-plus

Answer (score 0):

If you want both view controllers managed by your `UISplitViewController` to be visible in any orientation, you need to set its `preferredDisplayMode` to `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible`.

As for the setup of your view controller hierarchy, it looks like you may be confusing view controllers with views. If you want two simple `UITableViews` to sit next to each other, why not make both the master and detail view controllers instances of `UITableViewController` rather than trying to embed `UITableViewController`s within `UIViewController`s?

Using your notation and classes, this would looks like this:

```
UISplitViewController --masterview--> Table1ViewController
UISplitViewController --detailview--> Table2ViewController
```

Note: "segue" means "transition." A segue will determine how the user gets from one view controller to the next; it does not describe how one view controller can be embedded in another.

Comment: I solved this issue, but now I get other issue. Can you help me solve it?